# How do I get the className of a event.target in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to get the user.id of the user that I clicked on, so that I can use it as a query parameter in a fetch(). However, what setClickedUserId is passing/assigning to my clickedUserId state is the following: MuiButtonBase-root%20MuiListItem-root%201%20MuiListItem-gutters%20MuiListItem-button
----My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import ExpandLess from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMore from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
import AddBoxOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddBoxOutlined';

// Global context
import globalContext from './globalContext';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(-2.0),
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: '#3F0E40',
    color: 'white',
  },
  nested: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(-3.5),
  },
  nestedAdd: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(3.5),
  },
  nestedAddText: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(0.5),
  },
}));

/**
 *@return{any} nestedList
 */
export default function DmsList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  console.log('I am inside DmsList!!');
  // Global Context
  const {setMobileOpen} = React.useContext(globalContext);
  const {currentDmdWith} = React.useContext(globalContext);
  const {setChannel} = React.useContext(globalContext);
  const {clickedDms, setClickedDms} = React.useContext(globalContext);
  const {setClickedUserId} = React.useContext(globalContext);

  const handleClickUser = (event) => {
    setMobileOpen(false);
      setClickedDms('true');
      setChannel(event.target.innerText);
      setClickedUserId(event.target.className);
      console.log(clickedDms);
  };

  const handleClickAdd = () => {
    setMobileOpen(false);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <List
      component="nav"
      aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
      className={classes.root}
    >
      <ListItem button
        onClick={handleClick}>
        {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        <ListItemText primary="Direct Messages" />
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component="div" disablePadding className={classes.nested}>
          {currentDmdWith.map((user) => (
            <ListItem button className={user.id} onClick={handleClickUser}>
              <ListItemIcon className={user.id}>
              </ListItemIcon>
              <PersonIcon className={user.id} color='white'/>
              <ListItemText className={user.id} primary={user.name} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
          <ListItem button
            onClick={handleClickAdd}
            className={classes.nested}>
            <ListItemIcon>
            </ListItemIcon>
            <AddBoxOutlinedIcon className={classes.nestedAdd}/>
            <ListItemText
              className={classes.nestedAddText} primary="Add Teammate" />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Collapse>
    </List>
  );
}
```

I would use event.target.id, because it actually gets the div's id and not a bunch of mumbo jumbo, but when I do put id = {user.id} in a ListItem I have to click on a very specific spot, the leftmost side, because if I click on an a person icon or the area with text, event.target.id is a assigned a blank and makes my fetch() return a 404 error.

Comment: Can you add an example we can look at ? Does currentDmdWith always have a value? or can it be undefined? Second of all, i would recommend not to pass information that way... It seems you are overcomplicating things. I dont quite understand what you are trying to accomplish? Why would you send the user.id as a className?

Comment: try e.currentTarget - this always returns the element that the event listener is attached to

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to read the information out of the `Event` object, pass the info that you need in the `handleClickUser` function through the `onClick` prop.

```
<ListItem 
  button 
  className={user.id} 
  onClick={() => handleClickUser(user.id)}
>
```

```
const handleClickUser = (userId) => {
  setClickedUserId(userId);
};
```